# Is it better to send query string or serialize data when sending a GET request?

Tags: c#, http, get-request

I am using an ADO.NET app to frequently send data to a web server.  And there are thousands of machines doing this so it will become heavy on the server.
I have a bunch of stuff I would like to send.  Lets call them v1, v2, ... , v10 which are very different data.  So which of the following approaches to send them is better?

1) Send them as different parameters like the following:

```
..ashx.cs?v1=value1&(.&.&.)&v10=value10
```

or

2) Serializing them from a class and sending it like the following:

```
..ashx.cs?vSerialized=(serializedInfo)
```

And if you have a better of doing this let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what context are you interested in being "better" -- better performance, better security, better maintainability/troubleshooting/debugging, etc.?

Comment: Beware of of premature optimization.  I suggest you pass the parameters the usual straightforward way until you have evidence that it is a problem.  It seems unlikely that this is going to be the bottleneck.

Comment: We are worried about the data being intercepted, so we are currently encrypting the information before sending them.  What we are mainly worried about is performance.

Comment: If you're worried about the data being intercepted, use SSL. That way, you let the (highly-optimised and fully tested) infrastructure take care of the encryption/decryption.